# How to make your laravel command run two days in a week and twice a day?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have a laravel 5 app. I want to run a laravel command twice a day in two days of the week. My attempt is as follows:

```
$schedule->command('supervisor:reminder')->weekly()->mondays()->thursdays()->twiceDaily(6, 13);
```

I don't get the reminder emails. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check laravel.log for errors and cron log for cron execution logs(for ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/a/56811)

Answer (score 0):

Using the command below,my application is sending notifications to managers on Mondays and Thursdays at 7AM and 2PM.

```
$schedule->command('manager:reminder')->cron('0 6,13 * * 1,4');
```